# How to make a transparent background with imagecreatetruecolor in gd in php?

Tags: php, gd

I have a problem with imagecreatetruecolor function , i write this code but it make my background white can somebody tell me where i go wrong? I have a array of input image and first i make a empty layer of an first image width and height and try to make it transparent

```
foreach($form_fields as $fm) 
{   
    $layer = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fm));

    $layerWidth = imageSX($layer);
    $layerHeight = imageSY($layer);
    if (!isset($slate))
    {
         $slate = imagecreatetruecolor($layerWidth, $layerHeight);
         imagealphablending($slate, false);
         $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($slate, 255, 255, 255, 127);
         imagefill($slate, 0, 0, $trans_colour);
            imagealphablending($slate,true);
             imagesavealpha($slate,true);



    }
    imagecopy($slate, $layer, 0, 0, 0, 0, $layerWidth, $layerHeight);
    imagealphablending($slate,true);
    imagedestroy($layer);
}
imagetruecolortopalette($slate, false, 256);
imagepng($slate, $CreatedAvatar);
imagedestroy($slate);
```

Comment: I think you need this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php

Comment: i put it instead of imagefill but it make my background black

Comment: It would have to be an image type that supports transparency? Like .png

Comment: yes sure, i use png image type